# If i get a random line is it possible to get the line 2 below it?

Tags: python

If i get a random line through this code:

```
import random
import time

with open("Songs.txt","r") as f:
    for i in range(random.randint(1,8)):
        line = f.readline()

print("The First Letter Is:",line[0])
```

How would i then using the random line selected find the line 2 below?

For example in my list if i have:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E

If the randomly selected line prints "A" how would i get the program to store "C" into a variable and so forth

Thanks to the comment i now have this, thanks everyone!

```
import random
import linecache
rand_line = random.randint(1,8)
song = linecache.getline("Songs.txt", rand_line)
Star = len(song)
print("The first letter of the song is:",song[0])
print("The song has",Star,"letters in the title.")
print("And the artist is:",linecache.getline("Songs.txt", rand_line + 9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific code, you can get the line two below the selected line like this:

```
import random

with open("Songs.txt","r") as f:
    for i in range(random.randint(1,8)):
        line = f.readline()
    next(f, None)
    two_below = next(f, None)

print(line, end='')
print(two_below, end='')
```

Example output:

```
C
E
```

More generally, you can consider using the [`linecache`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/linecache.html) module for random access to text lines.

Demo:

```
>>> import linecache
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> rand_line = random.randint(1, 8)
>>> rand_line
3
>>> linecache.getline('Songs.txt', rand_line)
'C\n'
>>> linecache.getline('Songs.txt', rand_line + 2)
'E\n'
>>> linecache.getline('Songs.txt', 1000)
''
```

Comment: thanks i used this as the basis to write more of the code really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store all lines in memory with `lines = list(f)` and then if your random number is `i` getting the line you want would be simply lines[i+2]. Something like this:

```
import random

with open("Songs.txt","r") as f:
    lines = list(f)

i = random.randint(1, 8)
print("The First Letter Is:",lines[i][0])
print("Other letter is:", lines[i+2])
```