# Remove blank line that appears after every string

Tags: python, random

This program works fine but I'm having trouble removing the blank lines after every player. I've tried to use `.strip` but I get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

```
import random

def random_player(datafile):
    with open (datafile, 'r') as read_file:
        the_line = read_file.readlines()
        print(random.choice(the_line))

random_player(file_name)
random_player(file_name)
random_player(file_name)
random_player(file_name)
random_player(file_name)
```

What I get:

```
Toney Douglas

Adonal Foyle

Nate Hawthorne

Joe Stephens

Gary Payton II
```

What I want:

```
Toney Douglas
Adonal Foyle
Nate Hawthorne
Joe Stephens
Gary Payton II
```

Comment: Also, consider using `linecache`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268537/3620003) is a demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lines in `read_file` contain newline characters, and then `print` adds another one by default. You can avoid the second newline with `print(random.choice(the_line), end='')`.

Other comments:

- `read_file.close` does nothing because you forgot to call the method.
- In addition, even doing `read_file.close()` would be pointless because employing the `with` statement already handles closing the file.
- `the_line` is a confusing variable name because it's many lines.
- You should probably read the file into memory once (it does not seem to be gigantic) instead of opening and reading it every time `random_player` is called.

Answer (score 1):

**timgeb**'s answer is one way to do it, you could also try trimming the newline at the end of your lines.

```
print(random.choice(the_line).strip('\n'))
```